# How to change heading font style in memoir?

Tags: fonts, formatting, header-footer, memoir

Please take a look at the image below. How do I change the heading font style? As you can see it wraps over in two lines because the chapter title is too long. I did read memoir manual but the only thing I found was `\makeheadrule` and I already used it to get the underline effect for the heading (`\makeheadrule{headings}{\textwidth}{0.3pt}`). I am not sure how to change it further to reduce the font size as it uses the built-in `headings` style. I couldn't figure out how to modify `headings` style. Any ideas?

Also after I have changed the size, I'd like to reset it back for further chapters as they don't have that long chapter title.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `\markboth` command to manually customize the mark (in particular, the font to be used for the mark) used in the header for a particular chapter. I don't like this approach, since it will render the document layout inconsistent (some chapters will have a header in normal size and one chapter will have a header in a smaller font).

A better option would be to use the second optional argument of the `\chapter` command (a feature implemented in `memoir`) to use a shorter text for the header; the following example illustrates these approaches:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}

% using \markboth to change the mark used
\chapter{Selective printing and deleting of certain lines}
\markboth{\small \chaptername\ \thechapter. Selective printing and deleting of certain lines}{}
\section{Test section}
\lipsum[1-30]
% using the second optional argument of \chapter to change the header text
\chapter[Selective printing and deleting of certain lines][Selective action on lines]{Selective printing and deleting of certain lines}
\section{Test section}
\lipsum[1-30]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `\copypagestyle` macro (memoir manual, p. 121) to clone the `headings` pagestyle and add a fontsize-changing macro to the default definition (which may be found at p. 124). Even better, use a shorter title for the header as suggested by Gonzalo Medina.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\makeheadrule{headings}{\textwidth}{0.3pt}

\copypagestyle{fnsizeheadings}{headings}
\makeevenhead{fnsizeheadings}{\thepage}{}{\footnotesize\slshape\leftmark}
\makeoddhead{fnsizeheadings}{\footnotesize\slshape\rightmark}{}{\thepage}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fnsizeheadings}

\chapter{Selective printing and deleting of certain lines}

\section{foo}

\lipsum[1-8]

\cleardoublepage
\pagestyle{headings}

\chapter[Selective printing and deleting]{Selective printing and deleting of certain lines}

\section{foo}

\lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

A third thing to do is not to use pure capitals in the header, they take up a lot of space.

Simply issue

```
\nouppercaseheads
```

before activating the page style will deactivate the automatic upper casing

Answer (score 0):

This is a somehow long solution (using Memoir class):

```
% New Page Style
\makepagestyle{MPS} 
%
\makeatletter % \@chapapp
\makepsmarks{MPS}{%
\nouppercaseheads
\createmark      {chapter}      {both} {shownumber} {\@chapapp }{. \ }
\createmark      {section}      {right}{shownumber} {}{. \ }
\createmark      {subsection}   {right}{shownumber}   {}{. \ }
\createmark      {subsubsection}{right}{shownumber}   {}{. \ }
\createplainmark {toc}          {both} {\contentsname}
\createplainmark {lof}          {both} {\listfigurename}
\createplainmark {lot}          {both} {\listtablename}
\createplainmark {bib}          {both} {\bibname}
\createplainmark {index}        {both} {\indexname}
\createplainmark {glossary}     {both} {\glossaryname}   
}

\makeheadrule{MPS}{\textwidth}{2\normalrulethickness}

\makeevenhead{MPS}{ 
\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{lmss}\selectfont \small\thepage}
{}{ 
\fontencoding{T1}
\fontfamily{lmss}\selectfont 
\small\leftmark 
}

\makeoddhead{MPS}{
\fontencoding{T1}
\fontfamily{lmss}\selectfont 
\small\rightmark 
}
{}
{\fontencoding{T1}
\fontfamily{lmss}\selectfont
\small\thepage}
```

where it is used the Latin Modern Sans Serif as in document in overleaf.